How can I create an effect plot with data
Here is an example dataset:
structure(list(SecondFactor = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("D_AMPER = 1", 
"D_AMPER = 2", "E_DPT = 1", "E_DPT = 2"), class = "factor"), 
    FirstFactor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("A_CONC = 1", 
    "A_CONC = 2", "B_TEMP = 1", "B_TEMP = 2", "C_PT = 1", "C_PT = 2", 
    "D_AMPER = 1", "D_AMPER = 2"), class = "factor"), y = c(31.7083333333333, 
    29.4583333333333, 29.2083333333334, 31.9583333333333, 29.5, 
    28.9166666666667, 33.9166666666667, 30, 22.0833333333334, 
    36.3333333333333, 39.5833333333333, 24.3333333333333, 29.4166666666667, 
    31.5833333333333, 31.75, 29.5833333333333), section = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
    ), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

I would like to create an effects plot, using these estimated marginal means, all on the same chart using ggplot2. It would look something like this (which I manually stuck together in Excel):

But I have been absolutely stuck. I can get all the points on the graph, but they are overlapping. Ideally, this would use no additional packages beyond tidyverse and ggh4x.

Here’s a quick and simple approach that could be made prettier by fiddling with the theme. I map SecondFactor to group so that the lines connect, and add it to label so the lines are labeled.
ggplot(df, aes(FirstFactor, y, group = SecondFactor, label = SecondFactor)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(FirstFactor == last(FirstFactor), .by = section)) +
  facet_wrap(~section, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")


You might also consider ggrepel to tidy up the label spacing, or geomtextpath to apply the labels along the lines themselves.

Brilliant, thanks!

In base graphics, using matplot in by, we could do sth like this.
png('foo.png', width=8.75, height=2, units="in", res=300)
par(mfrow=c(1, length(unique(df$section))), mar=c(2, 0, 0, 0) + .75, 
    oma=c(0, 3, 0, 0))
by(df, ~section, \(x) {
  clr <- c('red', 'green')
  m <- matrix(x$y, ncol=nrow(x)/2, byrow=TRUE)
  matplot(m, pch=20, type='o', col=clr,
          lty=1, xlim=c(.625, 2.375), ylim=range(df$y), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE) 
  if (length(lb <- levels(droplevels(x$SecondFactor)))) {
    legend('topleft', pch=20, col=clr, legend=lb, bty='n', cex=.7,
           y.intersp=1.3)
  }
  pu <- par()$usr
  axis(1, pu[1:2], FALSE, tck=0)
  segments(1:2, pu[3], 1:2, pu[3]*.965, xpd=TRUE)
  mtext(levels(droplevels(x$FirstFactor)), 1, .75, at=1:2, cex=.6)
})
axis(2, axTicks(2), line=-.75, outer=TRUE, las=1, cex.axis=.95)
axis(2, par()$usr[3:4], line=-.75, outer=TRUE, tck=0, labels=FALSE)
mtext('y', 2, 1.5, TRUE, las=1, cex=.8, at=.6)
dev.off()



Thank you - it is very helpful to see it in base graphics too!
